# No value accessor for form control with path: 'keywords -> 0'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a form using Angular Reactive Forms. The field I'm trying to add is a list of Checkboxes. The Checkbox will indicate the presence of a keyword, which is actually an object and not a string value. I could convert a string to the object during an onChange or onSubmit later on. The issue I am having is the checkboxes won't appear because it cannot find them in the `FormArray`.

TS:

```
// class member:
availableKeywords = [
   {value: false, viewValue: 'Impetus (Rush)', valueId: 0},
   {value: false, viewValue: 'Guard (Taunt)', valueId: 1}
];


// in ngOnInit:

this.cardForm = new FormGroup({
    // ...
    keywords: new FormArray([]),
}

// after building my form, still in ngOnInit

// find all the keywords that are present in the "card" object (DBO), and enable them in my available keywords list

this.availableKeywords.filter((akw) => this.card.keywords.find(ckw => ckw.valueId === akw.valueId)).forEach(kw => kw.value = true);

//Now, add all the available keywords to the form with their current states:

const keywordArray = this.cardForm.get('keywords') as FormArray;

this.availableKeywords.forEach(akw => {
    keywordArray.push(new FormControl(akw));
});
```

HTML:

```
<section formArrayName="keywords">
  <div *ngFor="let keyword of availableKeywords; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="i">
      {{keyword.viewValue}}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have a `console.log(this.cardForm.value);` line right after all that, and it prints out the value of the form right before the error (both in screenshot).

The error:

[image: error]

Comment: Have you imported `MatCheckboxModule`?

Comment: Firstly, I'm so upset at myself for such a stupid mistake. Secondly, HOW IS THAT A USEFUL ERROR MSG? Thank you so much, smh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not importing `MatCheckboxModule`.